# I am trying to match a value in a txt file

Tags: python-3.x

```
def job():
current_balance = token_balance(contract, wallet)
with open('jade1.txt', 'a') as data:
    current_data = f'{current_balance}\n'
    test_string = 'current_data'
    matched = re.match("[a-z][0-9][a-z][0-9]+", test_string)
    is_match = bool(matched)
    print(is_match)
    if is_match:
        pass
    else:
        data.write(current_data)
```

I cannot seem to not input the current_data if it matches the value in the file. I only want to append the file if it is a new value. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Since we obviously don't have your input text file at hand... add some printouts and find out.

Comment: The txt file just pulls the token balance from bscscan. I've been up all night, the code is working great, it just repeats the token balance when it appends the file.

So I end up with:

13410.618802258
13410.618802258
13410.618802258
13410.618802258
13410.618802258
13410.618802258

quite a bit.